# crash generate dump

Tags: c++, crash, windbg

My application crashes occasionally at customer machine after running for 3-4 days. Is it possible to attach the application to a debugger like ADplus automatically when the application starts? This is for generating the dump file whenever the application crashes.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224154/application-crash-with-no-explanation/5224518#5224518

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to use ADPlus I assume a windows only solution will do it.
In this case you could install a post mortem debugger. It will pop up as soon as your app crashes. I usually use windbg.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at the [`SetUnhandledExceptionFilter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680634(v=vs.85).aspx) function.

Answer (score 0):

IMO you wouldn't have to attach to the debugger when the process starts. Windows would look for a debugger when the process terminates and the location is set AeDebug RegistryKey

On x86 computer it is `\\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug`

`CDB` can be set as Postmortem debugger

> To change the postmortem debugger to
>   CDB, run cdb -iae or cdb -iaec
>   KeyString. When the -iaec parameter is
>   used, KeyString specifies a string to
>   be appended to the end of command line
>   used to launch the postmortem
>   debugger. If KeyString contains
>   spaces, it must be enclosed in
>   quotation marks. This command will
>   display no message if it succeeds, but
>   will display a failure message if it
>   fails. When CDB is the postmortem
>   debugger, it will be activated
>   whenever an application crashes.

I would have something like `cdb -iaec ".dump /ma /u crashedapp.dmp;q"` to get a memory dump when the process terminates.

And if the OS is Vista SP1+ then registry can be configured to get a full memory dump using WER [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787181(VS.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787181%28VS.85%29.aspx)